# spark: read csv with multiple delimiters

Tags: pyspark

How best to read a CSV with pyspark (2.0+) with multiple delimiters?
Each record ends with a text string which also contains spaces. I dont believe that it is possible to specify grok-like regexp patterns while reading spark csv - whats a good technique to do this?

```
<31>Dec 21 17:02:08 KKM-WiFi24K-CCR3 D8:16:C1:29:XX:XX (10.212.146.XXX): idle timeout <600> from RADIUS
<31>Dec 21 17:02:08 KKM-WiFi24K-CCR3 D8:16:C1:29:XX:XX (10.212.146.XXX): adding ip->user binding
```

Answer (score 0):

As CSV means comma separated value.  So you don't need to use regex or simililar technology.

There are a lot of library for each language to read CSV file.

I did use Datatable once to read CSV file. It's much more easier and fun to use. But who doesn't like javascript right?
Here is the link: https://datatables.net